# SQL adding in table rows with same id and different second id

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a databasw that has 2 columns.
First is category id, the second is group id.
Both are primary.
And i need to add to the table to the same category id some rows with group id 1 and 2.
I mean all the categories need to have groups 1,2,3

```
    INSERT INTO `ps_category_group` (`id_category`, `id_group`)
SELECT `id_category`, 2 FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT `id_category`,`id_group` From `ps_category_group`) as x;
```

gives me

> ## 1062 - Duplicate entry '2-2' for key 'PRIMARY'

Comment: Please tell us more about the structure of your tables, with especial mention to be given to any auto increment values or how you go about finding the new primary key values for a new record.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are selecting values from the same table for inserting into the table.  Then you are asking why you are getting primary key violations?  Of course you are; that is exactly what your query is doing.

Based on the description, you seem to want:

```
INSERT INTO `ps_category_group` (`id_category`, `id_group`)
    SELECT `id_category`, 2
    FROM `ps_category_group`
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE id_category = VALUES(id_category);  -- This does nothing if the value already exists in the table
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply. I'm pretty new to SQL. Your code gives `#1052 - Column 'id_category' in field list is ambiguous` error.